# How to stop tcsh from asking when using TAB with many rows?

Tags: csh, tcsh

I have an irritating shell at work which asks me for confirmation every time I press TAB and the list is about to be big:

> There are 96 rows, list them anyway? [n/y]

I've been looking for a way to get rid of it in the [tcsh man](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Completion_and_listing.html), but failed to find a way.
When looking for similar questions, I get mostly people who want to cancel the autolisting, but nobody wants to enhance it...
In case it matters, autolist value is defined but empty (set autolist)

Someone knows how to tackle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled with the `listmax` and `listmaxrows` settings; from the manpage:

```
listmax and listmaxrows can be set to limit the number of  items  and
rows  (respectively)  that  are listed  without asking first.

[..]

   listmax (+)
           The  maximum number of items which the list-choices editor com‐
           mand will list without asking first.

   listmaxrows (+)
           The maximum number of rows of items which the list-choices edi‐
           tor command will list without asking first.
```

The default is unlimited, so they were probably added to your `~/.cshrc` or `~/.tcshrc`, or they're set in the system-wide files in `/etc`.

At any rate, you can disable it with `unset`:

```
unset listmax listmaxrows
```

Comment: Excellent! can you please tell me where can I find such information in the future, so I won't have to nag the community on tcsh issues?

Comment: @user2141046 I just found it in the manpage. Searched for "rows" since that was in the error message, and it was the first hit :-)

Comment: Ouch... English isn't my native language, so large blocks of text scare me away...  will search better next time... thanks